# What do the icons mean next to the column names in IntelliJ?

Tags: mysql, database, intellij-idea

[image]

Could somebody explain at least these 3 versions?

1. yellow column in table
2. empty table
3. no icon

Comment: The first one is for column. The second one should be for table(though I have no idea why it's appearing beside *nationality*). Reference : https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html

Answer (score 3):

The yellow indicates the column has got an index. You can have a look at the following link for more context.
[Database tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html)

Comment: Do you have an idea, what it means if a column does not have an icon at all?

Comment: Here is a direct link to the fragment that includes a symbol chart that I was looking for: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/database-tool-window.html#possible-icon-combinations-for-columns